# WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, homebrew

> WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Seeing this warning on my local machine when I startup my Rails application.

- Ruby 3.1.4
- Rails 6.1.7.4
- mysql2 gem version 0.5.5
- mysql 8.1 installed through homebrew
- macOS Sonoma Public Beta (23A5312d)

Just curious as to what I need to do to fix this warning. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did some Googling around and found these two pieces of info:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-auto-reconnect.html
- https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1322

On my end, it seems that simply removing `reconnect: false` from my `database.yml` stopped the warning from showing up.

Since `false` is the default setting, anyway, it seems okay to remove it? I'm guessing this could change as the development process goes on.

Comment: Thanks. It directly points out the rootcause of it. I removed `reconnect: true` and the issue resolved on my side.