# Handling reconnection of MySQL (MariaDB) database without MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT

Tags: qt, mysql-connector, qsqldatabase

Currently I have this code:

```
Orders::Orders(QObject *parent) : QObject{parent}
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "orders");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("database");
    db.setUserName("user");
    db.setPassword("password");
    db.setConnectOptions("MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT=TRUE;");
    db.open();

    _model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
    _model->setTable("orders");
    _model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    _model->select();
}
```

that runs on Ubuntu 22.10, Qt 6.4.0 and MariaDB v15.1.
At runtime I get this warning:

> WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

I read [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqldatabase.html) they decided to remove the autoconnection feature completely.
I also searched in other questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76931038/warning-mysql-opt-reconnect-is-deprecated) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76875569/warning-mysql-opt-reconnect-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-versi), but they just focus about the warning itself.

I'm fine I can remove the option, but I don't understand how I should handle the reconnection then.

For example, this is one of my functions that rely on the database access:

```
void Orders::setOrderState(QString machine, QString id, DbOrderStates state)
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("orders");
    QString sql = QString("UPDATE orders SET states_id=:state WHERE id=:id AND machine=:machine");
    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.prepare(sql);
    query.bindValue(":state", static_cast<int>(state));
    query.bindValue(":id", id);
    query.bindValue(":machine", machine);
    query.exec();
}
```

When I execute this function I want to be sure the database is connected. What am I supposed to do? I have to check the return value of `prepare()` and if it fails I have to reconnect to the database blocking the execution of this function?

I didn't find a signal from [QSqlDatabase](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqldatabase.html) that tells me when the connection drops.

Also, I learnt I cannot use `QSqlDatabase::isOpen()` since it just returns if the database *was* opened, not the connection is still open at the moment of the call.

Comment: You should ask the mysql people on how to change it - MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is a mysql option which is only passed through by Qt sql driver. And since the driver does not notify anyone when the connection is dropped, QSqlDatabase can not tell you either.

Comment: @chehrlic are you saying I'm off-topic here?

Comment: Where can I find the "mysql people"?

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong, you just blame the wrong people. The mysql devs decided to deprecate this. Nothing Qt can do against it.

Comment: @chehrlic I apologize, but I'm not blaming anyone! I'm just asking how to detect and reconnect to a database without this feature. Surely there is a method, I just don't know it :)